# multi--platform GEO analysis based in expression of single gene

Tags: r, microarray, geo

*This question has also been asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/491078/)*

I have a challenge in analyzing GSE34941( It has 4 platforms) according to the expression of a specific gene in R. First, which is the best way to group my patients according to the expression of a gene to high- and low-expression? Second, which is the best way to remove the batch effect of multi-platform analysis here?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe can try the ComBat to remove the batch effect